# Prometheus: How to calculate proportion of single value over time

Tags: prometheus

I would like to calculate the percentage time that a given metric is non-zero in a time range.  I know I can get the number of values in that time range using

`count_over_time(my_metric[1m])`

but what I would like is something like

`count_over_time(my_metric[1m] != 0) / count_over_time(my_metric)`

I can't do this because `binary expression must contain only scalar and instant vector types`.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the value can only be 0 or 1, then you can use `avg_over_time`.

If it can have other values, then you need to convert it to 0 or 1 via a recording rule:

```
my_metric_nonzero = my_metric != bool 0
```

And then you can do `avg_over_time(my_metric_nonzero[1m])`

See also https://www.robustperception.io/composing-range-vector-functions-in-promql/

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly.  Out of interest, why can I take a range of this recorded metric but not do it inline in a query: `avg_over_time((my_metric != bool 0)[1m])`?

Comment: `my_metric != bool 0` returns an instant vector based on current data, to which the `[1m]` range cannot apply.

Comment: @brian-brazil you probably mean `avg_over_time(my_metric_nonzero[1m]) ?`

Answer (score 0):

As of Prometheus 2.7, [you can do this using a subquery](https://www.robustperception.io/how-much-of-the-time-is-my-network-usage-over-a-certain-amount).

Specifically, the following query will tell you what % of the time your query was nonzero, using a trailing 1 hour average.

`avg_over_time((my_metric[1m] != bool 0)[1h:])`

Note that the linked tutorial recommends that you still use a recording rule "to avoid re-computing the entire hour worth of subquery output at every evaluation interval."

Answer (score 0):

While Prometheus provides [subqueries](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/), which can be used for estimating the proportion of samples, which aren't equal to zero, this doesn't give the exact value. For example, the following query gives the estimated proportion of non-zero `my_metric` values over the last hour:

```
avg_over_time((my_metric !=bool 0)[1h:30s])
```

But the estimation may be incorrect if the `step` value in square brackets after the `:` (`30s` in the example above) is bigger than the interval between raw samples stored in Prometheus (aka `scrape_interval`). In this case only a part of raw samples are taken into account when calculating the estimation. If the `step` is smaller than the `scrape_interval`, then some raw samples may be counted multiple times.

This issue is fixed in [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) with [count_ne_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count_ne_over_time) function. For example, the following query returns the real proportion of non-zero `my_metric` samples over the last hour:

```
count_ne_over_time(my_metric[1h], 0) / count_over_time(my_metric[1h])
```

If `my_metric` samples are always non-negative, then the query can be simplified further with [share_gt_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#share_gt_over_time):

```
share_gt_over_time(my_metric[1h], 0)
```